# I can not find any example of implementation of padstart () in a text-field of vuetify

Tags: textfield, mask, vuetify.js

I have a text-field of the number type, to which I need a mask of 10 zeros to the left of the number entered. For example, entry "890" and in the text-field should appear "0000000890". Note the padstar () function of javascript but I do not know how to implement it on the text-field of vuetify.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use masks:

```
<v-text-field
    v-model="myText" 
    return-masked-value
    mask="0000000000-##########">
</v-text-field>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "text-field-example",
    data() {
      return {
      myText: 'test'
      }
      }
  }
</script>
```

docs are here below the API table